# Why for loop doesn't work for 2D array with an overflow but still works for 1D array

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-errors

The for loop to store values to two 1D arrays can store and print values even with an overflow but why a program to store values to 2D array using for loop doesn't run when there is an overflow?

The following program runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i, a[5], b[6];
 for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] = i;
 }

 for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
   printf(" %d", a[i], b[i]);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

But why the following program doesn't run?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, a[5][5];

for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = j;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d", a[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

I tried to store the values in 2D array using nested for loop but it doesn't run. However, the program runs when 1D array is used.

Comment: Your loop is `for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` which is iterating over *six* elements in your five-element array. You have the same problem in the first program as well. Going out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Both programs have crossed the boundary：result of first:*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)  result of second： 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 1 2 3 4 0
 0 1 2 3 4 5
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: In the first example: The declaration `int a[5]` declares `a` to be an array of `5` integers.  So the valid indices for `a` are `0` - `4`.  Not `5`, and not `6`.  Similarly, `int b[6]` declares `b` to be an array of `6` integers.  So the valid indices for `b` are `0` - `5`.  Not `6`.  Indexing past the end of an array is a severe bug which can cause all sorts of unexpected behavior.  Don't do it.  The same problems occurs in the second, two-dimensional example.

Comment: I suggest deleting this question, and going through your code fixing all of the out-of-bounds indexing.  Then try your examples again.  Sometimes indexing past the end of an array "appears to work", but it's never safe, and you can never really know when it will break.  Try to be less sloppy, and don't make mistakes like this.

Comment: @TomKarzes, the question seems to be *about* the out-of-bounds indexing. Or some of that, at least.

Comment: "*The for loop to store values to two 1D arrays can store and print values even with an overflow*" -- are you sure?  You should not be, because the language spec does not support you on that point. You might in some examples see behavior that you interpret that way, but it is not safe to rely on that.  You might see different under different circumstances, or with small code variations, or on a different machine, or with a different compiler or compile options.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, yeah that could be.  In that case, I'd say undefined behavior sometimes does what you want, and sometimes doesn't.  But in the case of a 2d array, if you exceed the bounds of the second index, it will end up stomping on itself, which you'll probably notice.  And if you exceed the bounds of the first index, then iterate over the second, you'll end up stomping on a lot more addresses than in the 1d case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one that you shared works because you are lucky. When you say
`int a[5]` this means you allocated 5 unit for integer and it starts from zero to four. It does not include five.

Fixed code first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i, a[5], b[6];
 for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
 {
    a[i] = i;
    
 }
 for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
 {
    b[i] = i;
    
 }

 for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
 {
   if(i<5)
     printf("a= %d\nb= %d", a[i], b[i]);
   else
     printf("b=%d",b[i]);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

for the second again you shouldn't try to use boundaries
Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, a[5][5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = j;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d", a[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? And where did you make those changes? Please don't just post code to be copy-pasted, that tend to lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is a bad thing. Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know what you are saying but in VS Code the program doesn't run when for loop is used with an overflow of 2D array. But why 1D array program runs even when there is an overflow?

Comment: Can you share the error? Then i can say something.

Comment: there is no error message but VS code freezes